# Solving $-b<-a<b$ for true values

Tags: absolute-value

I am having trouble with the following problem:

> $$-b<-a<b$$
>
> The above equation is true for constants $a$ and $b$. Which of the following must be true:
>
> 1. $a<0$
> 2. $b>0$
> 3. $|a|<b$

---

**My attempt:** From the inequality, we have$$-b<a<b\implies |a|<b$$So $3$ is true. However, I'm not sure how to show whether $1$ and $2$ are true or not. Any insights?

Comment: 2. is true because $-b < b$ iff $b>0$. 1. is false, for example let $a=1$, $b=2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $|a| < b$, we can conclude that $b>0$.

Let $a=0$ and hence $(1)$ is false.